# How to retrieve the created vertices of cmds.polyExtrude on Maya

Tags: python, maya

I'm writing a script to change the position of the vertices created by an extrude command given a specific vector. But I can't find a way to get the newly generated vertices/faces/edges.

I tried looking in `cmds.getAttr('polyExtrudeFace1')` or the query mode of `cmds.polyExtrudeFacet`, but I can't find the right attribute/flag to get what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying `cmds.polyExtrudeFacet` onto a mesh, Maya will automatically select the new faces. Knowing this, it's easy to convert the face components to the new vertexes:

```
cmds.polySphere(name="pSphere1") # Create a sphere to test with.
cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("pSphere1.f[10]") # Extrude a random face.
sel = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(cmds.ls("*.f[*]", sl=True), fromFace=True, toVertex=True) # Convert faces to verts. Filter `ls` to only get face selections.
cmds.select(sel) # Select the newly created vertexes.
```

Comment: that's quite an useful property. And way more efficient than the other solution, even if it's more flexible. Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind that you have to use this method only on creation and if you are aiming this for a random user, he will have to use your tool to create extrudes.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if there is a nice way to get the new extruded component ids but you can easily find it if you have a tool to get the before state.
One other way would be to desactivate every construction nodes , enable the polyExtrudeFace one by one and fill up a dic and then re-enable everything.
Here is an example to select the latest vertices on an extruded object :

```
'''
This script only work on the last polyExtrudeFace and on vertex
'''
# get the object
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True)
# get the extrude nodes, useful to create a dic with all polyExtrudeFace new component ids 
extrudenodes = [e for e in cmds.listHistory(sel) if cmds.nodeType(e) == 'polyExtrudeFace']
#current vtx count
current_vtx_nb = cmds.polyEvaluate(sel, v=1)
# disable a polyExtude
cmds.setAttr("{}.nodeState".format(extrudenodes[0]), 1)
# get the previous number
previous_vtx_nb = cmds.polyEvaluate(sel, v=1)
# re-enable it
cmds.setAttr("{}.nodeState".format(extrudenodes[0]), 0)
# get the range
nb = current_vtx_nb - previous_vtx_nb
mrang = [current_vtx_nb-nb,current_vtx_nb]
# recreate the vtx s3election
out = ['{}.vtx[{}]'.format(sel[0], i) for i in range(*mrang)]
# select the vertex
cmds.select(out)
```

EDIT :

here is an example of the building dictionnary loop :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

'''
This script build the vertices data loop
'''

class Counter:
    idCounter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Counter.idCounter += 1


def loopIncSel():
    'relaunch the command to loop throught all key of the dic'
    if sorted(dataExtrude.keys()):
        count = Counter().idCounter % len(dataExtrude.keys())
        k = dataExtrude.keys()[count]
        cmds.select(dataExtrude[k])


# get the object
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True)
# get the extrude nodes, useful to create a dic with all polyExtrudeFace new component ids 
extrudenodes = [e for e in cmds.listHistory(sel) if cmds.nodeType(e) == 'polyExtrudeFace']
# dic data :
dataExtrude = {}
for n in extrudenodes:
    cmds.setAttr("{}.nodeState".format(n), 1)

# reverse the processus to re-enable, 
# note that if there is node in between creating vertices and faces, it won't work
for n in extrudenodes[::-1]:
    # get the previous number
    previous_vtx_nb = cmds.polyEvaluate(sel, v=1)
    # re-enable it
    cmds.setAttr("{}.nodeState".format(n), 0)
    #current vtx count
    current_vtx_nb = cmds.polyEvaluate(sel, v=1)

    # get the range
    nb = current_vtx_nb - previous_vtx_nb
    mrang = [current_vtx_nb-nb,current_vtx_nb]
    # recreate the vtx s3election
    dataExtrude[n] = ['{}.vtx[{}]'.format(sel[0], i) for i in range(*mrang)]
# select the vertex
# cmds.select(dataExtrude['polyExtrudeFace3'])
loopIncSel()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, clever trick to use the vertice count difference. Now, I just need to find a way to filter the result to apply the right vector to the right vertice. I'm thinking about extruding all edges, and after all the processing, recreate the face. But that's my problem.

Comment: very kind of you for the second exemple.